# How to fix npm vulnerabilities and moderate and high manually?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

When I run `npm install`, it says

[image: npm]

When I run `npm audit` it gives me list of tables, similar to this:

[image: npm]

I'm still new in node.js and those messages confuses me a lot. Is there any way to fix it manually or get rid of those messages, I can't do anything with?

Comment: Did you run `npm audit fix` and see how many issues remained?  This will update various packages to newer versions that have fixed the known vulnerabilities that npm audit is reporting.

Comment: It looks like that last error you can fix with npm audit fix --force  - That's going to upgrade a package by a major version. You might have to change how you are using that package, if it's API changed.

Comment: I runned `npm audit fix` https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeoSu.png

Comment: I runned `npm audit fix --force`. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucNzb.png